# 2 functions, 2 ajax requests, how to callback properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I created two functions.

- One to mark something as completed
- Another one to mark it as incompleted again

My functions:

```
function milestoneComplete() {
    $("td.milestone-check span.incomplete").click(function() {
        var milestone = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $.ajax({
            context: this,
            type: "post",
            url: "assets/ajax/milestones/milestone-mark_complete.php",
            data: { 'milestone': milestone },
            success: function(data) {
                $(this).addClass("complete");
                $(this).removeClass("incomplete");
            }
        });
    });
}

function milestoneIncomplete() {
    $("td.milestone-check span.complete").click(function() {
        var milestone = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $.ajax({
            context: this,
            type: "post",
            url: "assets/ajax/milestones/milestone-mark_incomplete.php",
            data: { 'milestone': milestone },
            success: function(data) {
                $(this).addClass("incomplete");
                $(this).removeClass("complete");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

On document load I call the functions with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    milestoneComplete();
    milestoneIncomplete();
});
```

And here I click them to trigger the functions:

```
<span class="complete icon-checkmark" data-id="5"></span>
```

I tried to call the opposite function in the success function of the ajax request, but then that request will be executed multiple times (see commented line).

How can I make this work, so I can perfectly mark it complete and then incomplete, and again complete, and so on?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you can call second function on ajax:success of first function

Comment: Create a single request to do both actions and save one request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a single request using a common class and use `.data()` to persist the status i.e. `complete` or `incomplete`.

*HTML*

```
<span class="commonClass icon-checkmark" data-id="5" data-status="complete"></span>
```

*Script*

```
//Bind event using a common class
$("td.milestone-check span.commonClass").click(function() {
    var milestone = $(this).data("id");

    //Url
    var url = "assets/ajax/milestones/";

    //maintain status using custom attribute
    var status = $(this).data('status');

    if( status == 'complete'){
        url += "milestone-mark_incomplete.php";
    }
    if(status == 'incomplete'){
        url += "milestone-mark_complete.php";
    }

    $.ajax({
        context: this,
        type: "post",
        url: url,
        data: { 'milestone': milestone },
        success: function(data) {
            $(this).data('status', status == 'complete' ? 'incomplete' : 'complete');
        }
    });
});
```

---

Otherwise, You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when generating elements dynamically or **manipulation selector (like removing and adding classes)**.

*General Syntax*

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

*Example*

```
$("td.milestone-check").on('click',  "span.incomplete", function(){
    //Your code
});

$("td.milestone-check").on('click', "span.complete", function(){
    //Your code
});
```

Comment: i believe you missed mapping `url` in ajax. Also you can reduce logic for url as `var url = "assets/ajax/milestones/milestone-mark_";` and just add incomplete.php/complete.php to it. Also not sure about it but will `this` not change in success?

Comment: @Rajesh, Thanks for suggestion, However OP is using `context` so `this` will refer to element in the `success` callback

Comment: Splendit answer, upvoted. You made it very clear! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass callback function as param to both methods.

```
function milestoneComplete(callback) {
        $("td.milestone-check span.incomplete").click(function() {
            var milestone = $(this).attr("data-id");
            $.ajax({
                context: this,
                type: "post",
                url: "assets/ajax/milestones/milestone-mark_complete.php",
                data: { 'milestone': milestone },
                success: function(data) {
                    $(this).addClass("complete");
                    $(this).removeClass("incomplete");

                    if(callback) {
                       callback();
                    }

                }
            });
        });
    }

function milestoneIncomplete(callback) {
    $("td.milestone-check span.complete").click(function() {
        var milestone = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $.ajax({
            context: this,
            type: "post",
            url: "assets/ajax/milestones/milestone-mark_incomplete.php",
            data: { 'milestone': milestone },
            success: function(data) {
                $(this).addClass("incomplete");
                $(this).removeClass("complete");

                if(callback) {
                   callback();
                }

            }
        });
    });
}
```

And then call it like below. For the first call I have passed a `callback` but not for second. And in function I am only triggering callback if it's exist.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    milestoneComplete(function() {
      milestoneIncomplete();
     });
});
```